# turning on https flag for cookie

Tags: php, html, cookies, setcookie, cookie-httponly

So I am using this legacy application which is in php 4.
I am trying to set the httponly flag and  secure flag on.

This is my code:

```
header( "Set-Cookie:". $cookieName."=".$sessId."; expires=".$expireSeconds."; sessionID=".$sessId.";path=".$path."; domain=".$domain."; httponly; secure");
```

The secure flag is set on but the httponly is not.

Could it because the URL uses https protocol?

EDIT:
Also, does the expire field take seconds.  right now,
$expireSeconds=14400;
How do I modify the code to rectify this if it doesnt expect seconds as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it via `header()` when there's [setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) available? This function is available in PHP4.

```
setcookie($cookieName, $sessID, $expireSeconds, $path, $domain, true, true);
                                                                ^--secure
                                                                      ^--http
```

Comment: the httponly flag is not available in setcookie function for php 4